# batch file does not delete files when using mpif90

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I use a batch file to compile a Fortran code then delete all of the intermediate file as following:

```
cls
del *.obj
del *.mod

mpif90 -free /exe:paparuni.exe   globalv.f90   io.f90   g2dsearch.f90   paparuni.f90

del *.obj
del *.mod
```

However, the batch file only executes until the compilation part. After that, it does not delete *.obj and *.mod file as I want. But if I use ifort instead of mpif90 then all obj and mod files are deleted. Do you know what happen and how can I delete files if I want to use mpif90.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'd suggest `mpif90` is a batch file, in which case you need `CALL mpif90`